# Errors when running basic.py an example in ViZDoom

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to install ViZDoom on Ubuntu20.04 system. I am following the steps given the following link https://github.com/mwydmuch/ViZDoom/blob/master/doc/Building.md. I use conda to create a environment, python=3.6.15, then successfuly install vizdoom=1.1.11

However, when i have done all of steps, run examples/python/basic.py ,I am getting the following error:

```
Available buttons: ['MOVE_LEFT', 'MOVE_RIGHT', 'ATTACK']
Available game variables: ['AMMO2']
Gtk-Message: 22:45:21.345: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
Gtk-Message: 22:45:21.347: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Failed to allocate memory from system heap
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ViZDoom/examples/python/basic.py", line 112, in
game.init()
vizdoom.vizdoom.ViZDoomUnexpectedExitException: Controlled ViZDoom instance exited unexpectedly.
```

Can anyone help me figure out what the issue is? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

can you try installing these  (assuming 64 bit )

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module
sudo apt-get install libatk-adaptor
```

if 32 bit

```
sudo apt-get intall  libatk-adaptor:i386
sudo apt-get intall libcanberra-gtk-module:i386
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I will try later.